# Getting errors in android app development

Tags: android, gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

In first line it is showing error:  the support library should not use the lower version(24) then the targetsdkversion(25)

in the second line error is: the support library should not use the lower version(23) then the compiledsdkversion(24)!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the same version for Target and Compile sdk.

Also if you use for example sdk version 25, you have to use version 25 for appcompat and other dependencies too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: have already implemented earlier but still getting the same issue...scroll down i have posted the pic for more clearance

Answer (score 1):

use

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
```

Target Version:

```
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Support Appcompat

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
```

Comment: have already implemented earlier but still getting the same issue...scroll down i have posted the pic for more clearance

Comment: @DummyMail download Android 7.1.1 API Level 25 and also try compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0. Is there a new error?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the **same versions** for `compileSdk` and `targetSdk`.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    ....
defaultConfig {
    .....
    targetSdkVersion 25
```

Moreover, you also have to use same dependency version of `appcompat` and `design` library. Otherwise, error will occur. You may use the following versions, sync the gradle and you are good to go :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: have already implemented earlier but still getting the same issue...scroll down i have posted the pic for more clearance